# Did anyone deploy Milvus on kubernetes cluster on-premise?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, milvus

I want to deploy Milvus to my kubernetes cluster on-premise and
[I follow this guide](https://tutorials.milvus.io/en-how-to-deploy-milvus-cluster-with-kubernetes/#0)

Step 1: I setup nfs server on my server with nfs-kernel-server (I'm able to mount to pod and mount to my other machine in the same network too)

Step 2: I install helm chart `charts/stable/nfs-client-provisioner` (I add the node selector in the end of deployment in template folder to choose which server can be used)

```
$ helm install nfs-client . -n milvus
  WARNING: This chart is deprecated
  NAME: nfs-client
  LAST DEPLOYED: Tue Mar  1 10:12:12 2022
  NAMESPACE: milvus
  STATUS: deployed
  REVISION: 1
  TEST SUITE: None

$ helm list -n milvus
  NAME          NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART                           APP VERSION
  nfs-client    milvus      1           2022-03-01 10:12:12.969901256 +0700 +07 deployed    nfs-client-provisioner-1.2.11   3.1.0

$ kubectl get pod -n milvus
  NAME                                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
  nfs-client-nfs-client-provisioner-7685d96cbc-wxfkb   1/1     Running   0          6m18s
```

Step 3: Clone branch 0.11.0 of https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus-helm.git

```
$ cd milvus-helm/charts/milvus
$ helm install --set cluster.enabled=true --set persistence.enabled=true --set mysql.enabled=true my-release  . -n milvus
  NAME: my-release
  LAST DEPLOYED: Tue Mar  1 10:33:17 2022
  NAMESPACE: milvus
  STATUS: deployed
  REVISION: 1
  TEST SUITE: None
  NOTES:
  The Milvus server can be accessed via port 19530 on the following DNS name from within your cluster:
  my-release-milvus.milvus.svc.cluster.local

  Get the Milvus server URL by running these commands in the same shell:
    export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace milvus -l "app.kubernetes.io/name=milvus,app.kubernetes.io/instance=my-release,component=mishards" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
    kubectl --namespace milvus port-forward $POD_NAME 19530 19121

  For more information on running Milvus, visit:
  https://milvus.io/

$ kubectl get pod -n milvus
  NAME                                                 READY   STATUS     RESTARTS   AGE
  my-release-milvus-mishards-7cb6574bb5-jrcf4          0/1     Init:0/1   0          6m23s
  my-release-milvus-readonly-8588bdd49-7wtwt           0/1     Pending    0          6m23s
  my-release-milvus-writable-6db7bfc647-qrd69          0/1     Pending    0          6m23s
  my-release-mysql-5f69d5bd87-99zd5                    0/1     Pending    0          6m23s
  nfs-client-nfs-client-provisioner-7685d96cbc-wxfkb   1/1     Running    0          21m
```

As you can see pod stuck and can not running. Did anyone deploy Milvus on kubernetes cluster on-premise. Please help me!!!

Comment: Try `kubectl describe pod -n milvus my-release-milvus-mishards-7cb6574bb5-jrcf4`

Comment: thx a lot, i'll take a try

Answer (score 0):

Something to check is if you have a custom kubernetes cluster domain. Milvus is hard coded with the default kubernetes cluster domain of `cluster.local`.  The problem with this is that it breaks service discovery as the etcd nodes can't find each other.

Answer (score -1):

After installing Milvus Operator, I had the same problem like you. On Doc page, it said:

```
"Milvus Operator first creates all dependencies like etcd, Pulsar, and MinIO, and then continues to create Milvus components. Therefore, you can only see the pods of etcd, Pulsar, and MinIO now. Once all dependencies are enabled, Milvus Operator will start all Milvus comenter code hereponents. The status of the Milvus cluster is shown as in the following output"
```

But pods kept pending, and cluster status kept Unhealthy.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: New questions should be posted as a *question*, not as an *answer*.